# AngularJS/ng-animate - Cross-fade animation with dynamic content

Tags: angularjs, css-animations, fade, ng-animate

I have a container on my page, which has a background and a min-height. Inside the container, I have several "page" divs which are toggled with ng-if logic. These pages are dynamic, so the parent container's height depends on the height of these children. The basic structure is like this:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="page">
      Page 1
   </div>
   <div class="page">
      Page 2
   </div>
</div>
```

So far, so good. Toggling between these pages works as I expect, and the container height stretches as required. However, I need to add a cross-fade transition between the pages, so that they nicely fade into each-other. To do this, I need to absolutely position the "page" elements within the container, so that the DOM does not jump around during the transition. However, obviously, this removes them from the document flow, and prevents the parent container from taking its height correctly. As the rest of my DOM relies on this height, it breaks my layout.

I have created a basic pen to illustrate the problem - uncomment the position: absolute in the second line to see how the cross fade should look:

http://codepen.io/JarredMack/pen/xbzWgx

Is there an elegant solution to this problem that doesn't require recalculating heights on the fly with Javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem by applying a position: absolute on the element that's ng-leaving, but keeping position: relative on the element coming in. It's not perfect, as the container height doesn't transition nicely with it, but it's a pretty clean solution aside from that:

```
/* Added this */
.ng-fade.ng-leave {
   position: absolute;
   top: 20px; /* Arbitrary positioning for the container padding */
   left: 20px;
}
```

http://codepen.io/JarredMack/pen/zxaWLx

If anyone has a suggestion to animate the container height for the transition (as height: auto won't animate), I'm all ears!

Comment: I was just about to answer you use  `.page.ng-leave` instead of `.page` :)

Comment: Also a workaround for the positioning would be to remove the `top` and `left` properties and instead apply a `border: solid 50px transparent` on your `.page`

Answer (score 0):

You can set the animation() events of the element like so - [Pen](http://codepen.io/dylanlawrence/pen/qEKoJa)

```
 app.animation('.ng-fade', function() {
  return {
    enter : function(element, done) {
      var rect = element[0].getBoundingClientRect();
      element.parent().css({height:rect.height+"px"}); 
      done();
    },
    leave : function(element, done) {
       done();
    }
  };
});
```